# How to give label to the icon button in flutter

Tags: flutter

How to give a label to this `IconButton`?

```
IconButton(
  icon: Image.asset('path/the_image.png'),
  iconSize: 50,
  onPressed: () {},
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it with "Column"

```
Column(
  children: [
     IconButton( icon: Image.asset('path/the_image.png'), iconSize: 50, 
       onPressed: () 
        {}, ),
         Text(//your label)
  ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ListTile` widget as follows:

Use this if you want the label to be the title of your ListTile:

```
ListTile(
           leading: IconButton( icon: Image.asset('path/the_image.png'), iconSize: 50, onPressed: () {}, ),
           trailing: Text('Your label'),
        ),
```

Or if you want it be a trailing one, use this:

```
ListTile(
           leading: IconButton( icon: Image.asset('path/the_image.png'), iconSize: 50, onPressed: () {}, ),
           title: Text('Your label'),
        ),
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `TextButton.icon` widget. It was created to do exactly that. [Read Documentation here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton/TextButton.icon.html)

Code example:

```
TextButton.icon(
    icon: Image.asset('path/the_image.png'),
    onPressed: () {},
    label: const Text("Your label here"),
)
```